# Web Cam in use notification on Windows

Tags: windows, api, winapi, ffmpeg, wpd

Is there a way for my Windows program to get notifications when a video device is in use. I know how to enumerate the devices using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377566(v=vs.85).aspx
I can also use ffmpeg to open the video device to check if it is available but it opens up the camera for that fraction of a time which I don't want.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use physical device object name of camera and use sysinternals handle utility to search for handle usage of camera

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/

to downlaod handle utility